# !! sytactic sugar to check undefined in javascript for boolean values

Tags: javascript

```
var x = false;

if (!!x) { // syntactic sugar for x ! =undefined
    alert('I will not be shown');
}
```

here we do have the value "false" for x and so it is defined .  Question here is that is it  a proper way to check undefined?

Comment: That depends on whether you want to accept or reject `!!""` and similar.

Comment: How about e.g. `typeof(x) != "undefined"`?

Comment: `!!x` is _not_ "syntactic sugar for `x != undefined`". Where did you hear that?

Comment: Sorry just realized that is not ! . So I think best way to check is    (typeof x !== "undefined") .... Thanks "Orbit" :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reject only `undefined` then better to use:

```
if (typeof x !== "undefined") {
   // code
}
```

because, `!!x` will neglect other values like `x = false` / `x = ''`. Simple for a truth test you can use:

```
if (x) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really no point to

```
if (!!x)
```

as opposed to

```
if (x)
```

as the boolean conversion performed by `!` is exactly the same thing that the `if` statement will do anyway.

The `!!` "trick" is useful when you want to force a boolean conversion and preserve the result:

```
var xIsTruthy = !!x;
```

After that, the variable `xIsTruthy` will contain either `true` or `false`.

Of course,

```
if (x)
```

will succeed when `x` is anything other than `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `false`, or `NaN`. Sometimes that's OK because you know that `x` is supposed to be, for example, either nothing or an object reference. However, if you need a more specific test, you have to write that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most widely used check for `undefined` (or not-`undefined`, which is what you are checking for) is:

```
if (typeof x !== "undefined") {
    console.log("x is defined");
}
```

As (I think) you have noted, your test will produce a `true` value for anything that is falsy, in other words, for `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `false`, and `NaN`.